# How can I view github workflow output parameters in github console?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have setup a reusable workflow which has output values that other steps use. How can I view those output runtime value in github action console? It helps to debug issues when working on a change for those parameters. But I can't find anywhere in github that I can view them.

Comment: Have you looked at [Using outputs from a reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-outputs-from-a-reusable-workflow)? The exposes [`outputs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs) that you may use to access the output parameters.

Comment: For debugging purposes, you might want to dump everything in the `outputs` on the console. For that you can use [`toJson`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#tojson) function e.g. in Bash you may do something like `echo '${{ toJson(needs.jobId.outputs) }}'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see outputs in same step which creates them, just dump `GITHUB_OUTPUT` file.

```yaml
- run:   |
         echo "var=value" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
         cat $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  shell: bash
```

If you want to see outputs after step which creates them, you can use [`toJSON`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#tojson) with partial `steps` context.

```yaml
- run:   echo "$OUTPUTS"
  shell: bash
  env:
   OUTPUTS: ${{ toJSON(steps.step-name.outputs) }}
```

If outputs comes from another job, just replace `steps.step-name.outputs` with `needs.job-name.outputs`

This solution is actually [mentioned in docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log) nowdays, but example provided shows dumping whole contexts only.